# Strange text insertion problem with Html.Partial C# Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Long time reader, first time poster.

I am having a problem when using Html.Partial to build my view.
At the bottom, inside, div-a and div-b is some auto generated text, basically one has a couple of new line operators, and both have one semi-colon. These insertions are not part of my partial view and I can't seem to find any information on the web.

If I refresh these pages via an ajax call and jquery.load() there is no semi-colon and everything is rendered as it should be.

index.cshtml:

```
@model Library.Models.TimeList

<div id="div-a">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller/Page.cshtml", Model);
</div>
<div id="div-b">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller/DifferentPage.cshtml", new Library.Models.TimeBlock());
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/PagesJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DifferentPagesJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

}
```

Here's an image. Its not entirely clear, but the text is supposed to be just under the white space.

[Strange semi-colon insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8tiV.png)

Thank you.
Kind regards,
Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need ";" when to call @Html.Partial(...)

Comment: Thank you very much. I LMAO a little too much when I read that.